# ¿Cómo hago para eliminar en un data frame a un grupo de columnas de un determinado tipo de clase?

Tags: r, dataframe

Tengo el siguiente data frame:

```
a<-sample(1:300, 10, T)
b<-sample(c("SI","NO"), 10, T)
d<-sample(c(T,F), 10, T)

df<-data.frame(a,b,d)
```

Como pueden ver son de distintas clases.

```
sapply(df, class)
```

```
        a         b         d         e 
"integer"  "factor" "logical"  "factor"
```

Mi pregunta es que función uso para quedarme solamente con los integer.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pues ya casi lo tienes resuelto, `sapply(df, class)` retorna un vector con las clases de cada columna, simplemente compáralo con la cadena `"integer"` y usa dicha comparación en la selección de columnas para generar el nuevo `data.frame`:

```
df[, sapply(df, class) == "integer", drop=FALSE]
```

Importante: La selección de columnas, por defecto, coerciona el resultado, cuando se selecciona una sola columna, a un vector. Con `drop=FALSE` nos aseguramos que el retorno de la selección siga siendo un `data.frame`.

Comment: Muchas gracias, por su apoyo.